The google cloud translate client library is not compiling, probably missing a package?
Hi I'm a student and I'm working on a project that will need to translate strings and am therefore using the google cloud translate API.
I have setup a project in the cloud console, included billing, and activated the API
however, the problem is with the nodejs client library. There must be some package I'm missing but I cannot figure it out.
as per google's tutorial on how to setup the client library I ran 'npm install --save @google-cloud/translate'. no problems
however whenever I include const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2; the program fails to compile and gives 70 errors almost all are 'module not found: cannot resolve ' in nature
enter image description here
maybe useful diagnostic information:

webpack version:5.90.3
react scripts version:5.0.1
node version: 21.7.3
react version: 18.2.0

Thank you for your help!
I have tried the node-polyfill-webpack-plugin, made the webpack.config.js and it did not work
I also tried react-rewired and that fixed some of the errors but it still didn't compile

What happens if you npm install util and npm install stream?

@DazWilkin I should have mention this in the 'what I tried' section, but I did try to install util, stream, crypto-browserify, querystring, etc. Eventually I got it down to 18 errors by doing a bunch of npm installs. Then I installed react-rewired and set up a config-overrride.js file. Brought it down to 4 errors. After adding some 'require.resolve("")' statements to it, it finally compiled! But then It had a runtime error because 'process' could not be found or something. I have given up on google translate and am now going to try deepL.

I think, in part, your issue results from a change to webpage Node.js Polyfills Removed. I'm not a Node developer but, I'm unable to repro your issue with a very simple index.js containing the the require("@google-cloud/translate").v2;. There may (!?) be issues using Cloud Translate  in a client-side JavaScript app.

@DazWilkin I've been looking at other stack overflow posts and I think your last comment about issues using Cloud translate client side is on the money. I found another post link that said you absolutely cannot use any modules in the node core API in the browser (because they contain C/C++ binaries I guess). All my "module not found" errors where for node core modules. I'm beginning to think that the cloud translate stuff needs to go on the backend. also thanks for your help btw

are you trying to run the Node.js application in a browser? It probably wouldn't work. You might need to build a backend that sits in between your browser client and the Google Translation API. The path looks like this: Browser -> Node.js Backend -> Google Translation API. The backend is the Node.js code that does 2 things: 1. Expose a REST API that browser can call, there are plenty of Node.js modules to do it. 2. Call Google translation API using the library you were coding. You can host this backend using GCP Cloud Run or Cloud Function.
